# How to bundle Vite Vue Router 4 into same chunk

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, vite, vue-router4

using vue cli, you can bundle vue route chunk together using web-pack

```
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    meta: { alreadyAuth: true },
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ '../views/public/Login.vue')
  },
  { path: '/splash', name: 'Splah', component: Splash },
  {
    path: '/portal',
    name: 'Portal',
    meta: { requireAuth: true },
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "portal" */ '../layouts/Dashboard.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "portal" */ '../views/portal/Portal.vue') }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm current using Vite for a project. Is there a way to bundle the chunk for example Dashboard and Portal together?

running nom run build will generate individual chunk file for Portal.js and Dashboard.js

Thanks

Comment: Does this info from the vue router docs help? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#with-vite

Answer (score 0):

There has a vite plugin which can help. [vite-plugin-webpackchunkname](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-webpackchunkname)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

not use dynamically import  will not seperate chunk.

```
import Login from '../views/public/Login.vue'
import dashboard from '../layouts/Dashboard.vue'
import Portal from '../views/portal/Portal.vue'

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    meta: { alreadyAuth: true },
    component: Login
  },
  { path: '/splash', name: 'Splah', component: Splash },
  {
    path: '/portal',
    name: 'Portal',
    meta: { requireAuth: true },
    component: dashboard,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: Portal }
    ]
  }
]
```